# function that accepts all numeric types (int, float, ..) and adds them

Tags: go

I would like to write a function that accepts two arguments of type `int`, `int8`, `int16`, ..., `float`, and `float64`. The type of arguments doesn't have to match. This function should take two arguments and add them. What is a good way to do this?

Essentially I want something like this:

```
func f(a interface{}, b interface{}) interface{} {
    return a + b
}

f(int8(1), int16(2))    // 3
f(float64(2.2), int(1)) // 3.2
```

Is there a way to do this in Go? I'm open to using reflection, but would also like to see ways without reflection if possible.

Comment: You can't add mismatched types anyway unless you make them the same type before performing the addition. Plus what should the return type be?

Comment: Many other languages, e.g. Java, let you add mismatched types. For ints, the return type would be larger of the two ints. For floats + ints, the return type would be float. This is a well established convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on @YandryPozo's answer, you can generate the combinations once, then you don't need to rely on formatting and parsing strings, or reflection. This will convert any numeric type to `int64` or `float64` to be added, returning one of those types. You could go through the individual cases and remove extra type conversions to only convert to the minimum common base which would be even more efficient, but then any type could be returned and you would have to type-switch all possible types on the return. You could even add `string` cases in there if you wanted to parse strings.

https://play.golang.org/p/e_4IMlsSR0 (or expanded out https://play.golang.org/p/M2niXz2It_)

```
func add(x, y interface{}) interface{} {
    switch x := get64(x).(type) {
    case int64:
        switch y := get64(y).(type) {
        case int64:
            return x + y
        case float64:
            return float64(x) + y
        }
    case float64:
        switch y := get64(y).(type) {
        case int64:
            return x + float64(y)
        case float64:
            return x + y
        }
    }

    panic("invlaid input")
}

func get64(x interface{}) interface{} {
    switch x := x.(type) {
    case uint8:
        return int64(x)
    case int8:
        return int64(x)
    case uint16:
        return int64(x)
    case int16:
        return int64(x)
    case uint32:
        return int64(x)
    case int32:
        return int64(x)
    case uint64:
        return int64(x)
    case int64:
        return int64(x)
    case int:
        return int64(x)
    case float32:
        return float64(x)
    case float64:
        return float64(x)
    }
    panic("invalid input")
}
```

If you want arbitrary precision for any arguments, without overflow or truncations, you could convert all arguments to `math/big` types. This example converts everything to a `big.Float` with a single type switch, and you could expand this like above to combine `big.Int` and `big.Float`.

```
func addBig(nums ...interface{}) *big.Float {
    var total big.Float
    for _, n := range nums {
        total.Add(&total, getFloat(n))
    }
    return &total
}

func getFloat(i interface{}) *big.Float {
    var f big.Float
    switch i := i.(type) {
    case uint8:
        f.SetInt64(int64(i))
    case int8:
        f.SetInt64(int64(i))
    case uint32:
        f.SetInt64(int64(i))
    case int32:
        f.SetInt64(int64(i))
    case uint64:
        f.SetUint64(i)
    case int64:
        f.SetInt64(i)
    case int:
        f.SetInt64(int64(i))
    case float32:
        f.SetFloat64(float64(i))
    case float64:
        f.SetFloat64(float64(i))
    }
    return &f
}
```

Comment: that's what I've been talking. Also you have multiple panic errors here like `case int64: return int64(x) + int64(y)` or uint to int assertion, don't you find it?

Comment: @MarcelNovy: those won't panic, they are subject to the same overflow/truncation rules. This could have checks for overflow and such, or you could also just replace all conversions with `float64`, or even use `math/big`. Regardless, the problem is very tractable, and doesn't require formatting and parsing strings.

Comment: right, it simply produce wrong result, see yourself `fmt.Println(add(int(255), ^uint64(0)))` . My point is- if you switch to `math/big` and then convert everything to `float64`, then how is it different from my solution? Simply replace big.Float.Parse to just few type switchers and get job done in few lines, do you need 2 mins for that?

Comment: @MarcelNovy: that's the result I'd expect given the types we're working with; and if you want arbitrary precision math, this could use math/big as well without the string interpolation. What I would not expect is a math function to use reflection, make 15 allocation, and take 10-50x longer to execute. Yes, your way works, I'm just showing a possible example using a type switch (which your example does implicitly though the fmt package).

Comment: Hmm this seems very verbose. I guess it is the only way. I'm writing a virtual machine and this code is a little crazy to use for implementing the `ADD` instruction. More worrisome is that a million comparisons need to happen just to do arithmetic...

Comment: @Max: the comparisons need to happen at some level, whether you see them in your code or whether they're done by the compiler. What you can do is limit yourself as much as possible to 2 or 3 primary types to reduce comparisons, i.e. `int64` `float64`. For example, Javascript gets by with only `float64` (though there are sometimes various optimizations going on under the hood), and cpython only uses a few numeric types for most operations, and upgrades numbers to arbitrary precision as needed.

Comment: @Max: I condensed the generated example down to a much smaller version with a via a helper function if it helps.

Comment: @JimB: Thanks. I'm still trying to figure out exactly what to do. I'm thinking about only allowing additions of the same type and have the `ADD` instruction take the width as a parameter. Then, an additional instruction `RESIZE` would be used to resize types so that additions could be carried out on two same sized types.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use reflection: [Reflection is never clear](http://go-proverbs.github.io)

You have two good options, you can use switch with .(type) or doing an explicit cast to your desire type like a.(int), something like this:

```
func f1(a interface{}, b interface{}) interface{} {

    switch ta := a.(type) {
    case int:
        switch b.(type) {
        case int:
            return a.(int) + b.(int)
        }
    case float64:
        switch b.(type) {
        case float64:
            return a.(float64) + b.(float64)
        }

    // you can add all your combinations ... byte, uint, int64, float32 etc. etc.

    default:
        fmt.Printf("unrecognized type '%T'\n", ta)
    }

    return nil // like super zero value of interface{}
}

func f2(a interface{}, b interface{}) interface{} {

    val_a, isAInt := a.(int)
    if !isAInt {
        return nil // a is not integer
    }

    val_b, isBInt := b.(int)
    if !isBInt {
        return nil // a is not integer
    }

    // more cast with different types (uint, floats, etc.)

    return val_a + val_b
}
```

Full example: https://play.golang.org/p/RCeJikC8py

Comment: The code does not support adding floats and ints, nor does it support adding `int8` to `int16`

Comment: I left you an example with only 2 types, you can use it as model to add or remove the types that you want to

Comment: I can't agree more with @Max here. This solution with type switcher is hard to imagine even for basic numeric types. What do we got is 10 types and 2 arguments, so the total possible number of switch combinations would be 10^2 = 100!

Comment: @JimB I'm afraid you're mistaken. You don't use typed values. Please try `fmt.Println(f1(int8(1), int16(2))) ` you'll get error

Comment: @MarcelNovy: oops, pasted Yandry's link, not mine. Well, I said I only spent 2 minutes on it, cut&pasted without [u]int16 cases.

Answer (score 0):

Adds any number of numeric arguments and even strings

```
func f(things... interface{}) interface{} {
    var x, y big.Float

    for _, v := range things {
        if _, _, err := x.Parse(fmt.Sprint(v), 10); err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        y.Add(&y, &x)
    }
    return y.String()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/HqCsy0UaDy